# Using dedup to find unique hosts. How can I find an average for the selected time frame?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

The goal is to provide percent availability. I would like to check every 15 minutes if the unique count for server1, server2, and server3 is equal to 3 for each interval (indicating the system is fully healthy). From this count I want to check on the average for whatever time period is selected in splunk to output an average and convert to percent.

```
index="os" sourcetype=ps host="server1" OR host="server2" OR host="server3"
| search "/logs/temp/random/path" OR "application_listener"
| dedup host
| timechart span=30m count
```

The count should be 3 for each interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how much of your requirements the example SPL solves, so I'll assume it does nothing.

Having `dedup` followed by `timechart` means the `timechart` command will only see 3 events - one for each host.  That doesn't make for a helpful chart.  I suggest using `dc(host)`, instead to get a count of hosts for each interval.

The `appendpipe` command can be used to add average and percentage values on the end.

```
index="os" sourcetype=ps host="server1" OR host="server2" OR host="server3" 
| search "/logs/temp/random/path" OR "application_listener"
| timechart span=30m dc(host) as count
| appendpipe [ stats avg(count) as Avg | eval Pct=round(Avg*100/3,2) ]
```